# Yodlee categories icons

Tags: yodlee

Is there any possibility to get the user transaction categories icon image from yodlee?

Right now i'm using "getUserTransactionCategories" this API call to fetch user transaction categories name. But i need Categories Icons too.

If so, please provide need information/details

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yodlee does not provide any icons for Transaction Categories. Its just the description. This allows customers to customize/choose their icons depending upon the solution they are building.